# Make a animation path separated by clicks

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, animation

I have a long text on powerpoint slide. Instead of separating it on multiple slides, I made an animation that moves it up using animation path, so that text hidden at bottom appears while text on top goes off screen.

However, I need more move animations to reaveal more text (the text takes more than 2 screens). This means, I need two (or more) animation paths (of the same length) and I want them to move obejct from position, where the last path has left it.

Instead, multiple animations always operate with objects original position. That's useless.

You can download test document, where I made an example of what I want: [animation test.pptx](http://u8.8u.cz//sracky/animation%20test.pptx)

Answer (score 0):

There may be more elegant solutions, but here’s one that seems to work:

1. Make multiple copies of your rectangle with the text in it. 
   Edit each one so it starts where the previous on stops. 
   For example, in your second copy, you would delete everything before “Lorem ipsum”. 
   You may need to do fine adjustments on the positions of the rectangles,
   perhaps by “nudging” them (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>
   and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>).
2. Set all of the rectangles (or, at least, all but the last one)
   to have solid white fill (or whatever solid color the background of your slide is).
3. You should have a separate animation for each rectangle
   (not many for the one, single rectangle). 
   In the “Effect Options…” dialog window of each animation
   (or, at least, all but the last one)
   set the “After animation” option to “Hide on Next Mouse Click”.

Comment: I'l test this, however, I've already discovered, that I was supposed to put path #2 start to path #1 end to get desired effect.